# jqueryMobile application is not working using jquryMobile framework js and css files relative path

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating an application using jquerymobile framework.

My application works as desired on localhost but once I upload my application on server, Javascript and css does not work and my application user interface and functionalities are being destroyed.

If I replace the javascript and css relative path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webroot/css/jquery.mobile.css" />
<script src="webroot/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="webroot/js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

to absolute jqueryMobile framework path

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://jquerymobile.com/test/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.css" />
<script src="http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquerymobile.com/test/js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

. It works.

**But on localhost the JS and CSS files relative path is working.**

Please suggest, where is the bug, in my application or in jqueryMobile js and css files.

Comment: what does your resources debugger says (resource panel in chrome debugger F12)? And with relative starting with cwd like ./webroot instead of just webroot?

Comment: I found it. There was an error in jquery.mobile.js file. While uploading on server, I think it was uploaded successfully. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

maybe if you try this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webroot/css/jquery.mobile.css">
<script src="/webroot/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/webroot/js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

note the slash at the start?

Comment: or without /webroot ? What is the the absolute URL to your server?

Comment: I created a dummy page. These menu is working on localhost but on server it is not working. http://www.questoons.com/nidhi-testing/testing/menus.html

Comment: href="css/jquery.mobile.css
src="js/jquery.js

Comment: somewhere there is a JS error, FireFox shows an error onload, thats why your script is not working. All of your CSS & JS are loading fine

Comment: I found it. There was an error in jquery.mobile.js file. While uploading on server, I think it was uploaded successfully. Now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

While uploading file on server using filezilla, I think file was not uploaded successfully. Then I changed the filezilla default transfer type setting to Binary. Not it is working fine.

If you want to change this setting then go to Edit > Settings > Connections > Transfers > File Types

Change "Default transfer type" Auto to Binary. Press OK button

It worked for me.